Adding MediatoR into a C# Console Application
I previously discovered the MediatoR and I'm impressed by it and wondering how to add it to a very simple C# console application.

dotnet add package MediatR

I have implemented the MediatoR as shown in the code below I have written everything in the Program.cs, however you definitely can create separate classes
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureService(services);
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            // Get MediatR instance
            var mediator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
            var response = await mediator.Send(new Ping());
            for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(response[i]);

            }
        }

        public static void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var mediator = services.AddMediatR(cfg => {
                cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);
            });
        }

    }

    public class Ping : IRequest<string[]>
    {
    }

    public class PingHandler : IRequestHandler<Ping, string[]>
    {
        public Task<string[]> Handle(Ping request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string[] cars = { "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" };
            return Task.FromResult(cars);
        }
    }

}


One hacky and imperfect way to do this, is to to reference the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package in your CLI app project, and then create a new ServiceCollection after this you could just add the mediator and all the other services you may need.
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddMediatR(/* config */);

// Dependency injection will not work perfectly, but inside of your classes, you could reference the IServiceProvider, instead of the services themself.
// For example:

class Dependency(IServiceProvider sp)
{
  private IMediator mediator => sp.GetRequiredService<IMediator>;

  public async Task Do(CancellationToken ct = default)
  {
    var request = new SomeRequest();
    var resp = await mediator.Send(request, ct);
    // do something with this.
  }
}


You can see how I use this for a discord bot in my project here

